# ASP.NET Controls in a ListView are databinding early on partial postback in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net ListView control that I’m having issues with the order in which the controls in that ListView are Databinding. The short question is that on a partial postback, the dropdownlist that is inside the listview InsertItemTemplate is databinding before the listview is, causing issues. Why is this happening when it seems to work fine in our .Net 3.5 code?

Some Background: We’ve had our software up and live in .Net 3.5 and it has worked fine. We’re working on migrating to .Net 4.5 and have ran into some issues. We have a control, similar to the one below, that loads fine on first load. However, after the first load if I click, for example, one of the edit buttons, the DropDownList databinds before the ListView does.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_Temp" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_TempBLL"
DataKeyNames="Id”" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"
OnDataBinding="ListView_Temp_DataBinding">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
        <tr id="tr_Header">
            <th></th>
            <th>Name
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholder">
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="tr_Item" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Insert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ValidationGroup="TempInsert">Add</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Names" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_Names" DataTextField="Names" 
                DataValueField="NameId" OnDataBinding="DropDownList_Names_DataBinding">
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</EditItemTemplate>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table id="Table1" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>No Names are specified.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

In our .Net 3.5 code the ListView Databinding method is called then the DropDownList Databinding method.
I’m wondering if anyone has seen this, has any solutions, or even suggestions at this point.

Here are some of the things we’ve tested.

1) Removing the ObjectDataSource for the DropDownList. (DropDownList is still databound)
2) Stripped off as many properties/methods/attributes as possible from the problematic dropdownlist and it still databound.
3) Stopped databinding the dropdownlist entirely, just added a shell DDL and it still runs the databinding event/method.
4) Add other control types (radio button, grid view) to see if it was unique to the DDL, they also databound.

Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Note: We just found out that this databinding doesn’t occur if you turn the ViewState of the ListView off. This potentially can lead us to a solution, but I’d like to understand and see documentation on this change and/or why it was made.